# Connecting to Oracle using ODP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

What can be improved in my code:

```
        using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                oracleConnection.Open();

                oracleCommand.CommandText = 
                "SELECT * 
                 FROM table_sample Table_Sample 
                 WHERE table_sample.id > 1000";

                using (var reader = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int id = reader.GetValue(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As the most "dangerous" thing I see the ugly string statement for database query.

I dont want to use Entity Framework for Oracle - cause its not as actual as one for MS SQL Server. And also some Oracle features are not supported.

Comment: You mean like having parametrized queries? Check the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ChrisWue maybe something that looks like EF syntax. Or anything else but not such a long string

Comment: @ChrisWue have look at your link - as I understand it is only the opportunity to use parameters, but string itself stay as ugly as before :) But thanks for this link!

Comment: AFAIK, you can use EF with other databases, including Oracle.

Comment: @svick its true. But the support for Oracle is not the best one. It is possible that in case of DB First some Oracle features cannot be used.

Comment: @MikroDel I don't see any Oracle-specific features in your code, so it looks like you didn't explain well what you want.

Comment: FYI I've used EF in combination with Oracle using https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `using` blocks to dispose your disposables, which is excellent. However these blocks increase the nesting of your code; since there's nothing between `using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))` and `using (var oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())` you could drop the curly braces and "stack" them, like this:

```
    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var oracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Within that scope, you're reassigning variable `Id` at each row that gets read; ultimately the value of `Id` will be that of the last row that was read. I doubt this is the intended behavior.

As for the string query, I agree it's "dangerous" - I prefer (by far) to use an object-relational mapper such as **Entity Framework** (which as @svick has mentioned has an Oracle provider), but never used it for anything other than SQL Server. I believe you could look into **NHibernate** as well, or shop around - something like *".net ORM for oracle"* should find you some interesting links :)

Answer (score 5):

You have one or two issues in your SQL query:

- **Pointless table aliasing:** You aliased the table `table_sample` as `Table_Sample`, which is pointless since identifiers in Oracle are case-insensitive.
- **Reliance on case-insensitivity of identifiers:** Once you alias the table name, you are supposed to use the alias, not the original.  Therefore, if you keep the pointless alias, your WHERE-clause should be `WHERE Table_Sample > 1000` to be consistent.  Your query happens to work, but only because Oracle identifiers are case-insensitive.

The most obvious solution is to get rid of the alias:

```
"SELECT * FROM table_sample WHERE table_sample.id > 1000"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `select *` as this will retrieve all the columns, instead you should be explicit as to what columns you want to retrieve.

Another potential issue with `select *` and then calling `reader.getValue([index])` is that you are relying on the index you are using for each column to be the same as the the order which they are in the table - this isn't maintainable and open to bugs, again explicitly stating the columns will ensure that the order you are expecting the column data to be in is correct.